# Eye candy in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm interested in creating *realtime* visual special effects.

I am limited to OpenGL (in particular, computing power of a MacBook Pro).

I want to learn more about doing cool UI/special effects (think the "computers/displays" in Iron Man / Avatar).

What are good books/resources for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about books, but check out NeHe and work through the tutorials:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Answer (score 0):

The NeHe tutorial is a good start as Timmmm suggest. I'd also recommend looking into [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) as a first start to get going with simple OpenGL stuff. Then when you get more and more comfortable  you can begin using the OpenGL view available in Cocoa and build a proper application, and then finally dig deep into ie this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356527) to get to know how to get that last performance piece out of the box.